# Alamofire 5 has no member named upload

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm migrating my project to Alamofire 5 and I stuck with one error which is regarding `Alamofire.upload`

Error -> `Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'upload'`

Code Below.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        formData.forEach({ (key, value) in
            guard let valueData = "\(value)".data(using: .utf8) else {
                return
            }
            
            multipartFormData.append(valueData, withName: key)
        })
        
        switch uploadOption {
            
        case .data(let data, let meta):
            multipartFormData.append(
                data,
                withName: "file",
                fileName: meta.fileName,
                mimeType: meta.mimeType
            )
            
        case .stream(let stream, let length, let meta):
            multipartFormData.append(
                stream,
                withLength: length,
                name: "file",
                fileName: meta.fileName,
                mimeType: meta.mimeType
            )
        }
},
```

Error appears on a first line -> `Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in`

Changing `Alamofire.upload` to `AF.upload` doesn't work for me.

Any ideas of how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next:

Alamofire.xcodeproj -> Build Phases -> Complie Sources

If (0 item), then "[+] Alamofire.swift".

Or if you have this error and you use 'alamofire5' branch just change Alamofire.upload to AF.upload according to documentation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server